# Adding CSS to React SSR Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-ssr

I am trying to add CSS to my component built in React using SSR, but I am unable to do so.

Things I've looked at:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader
- https://cssinjs.org/server-side-rendering/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.22
- webpack loaders

But in none the process is simple or clearly mentioned. The one which I tried a lot was isomorphic loader which seemed promising, but then it gave some vague errors after setting it in my CSS files:

> Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

This is my boilerplate package - https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr

How do I add styles to my React SSR code.

**Update**

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const path = require( "path" );
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require( "webpack-bundle-analyzer" );
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require( "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin" );

const plugins = [
    new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
];

if ( !dev ) {
    plugins.push( new BundleAnalyzerPlugin( {
        analyzerMode: "static",
        reportFilename: "webpack-report.html",
        openAnalyzer: false,
    } ) );
}

module.exports = {
    mode: dev ? "development" : "production",
    context: path.join( __dirname, "src" ),
    devtool: dev ? "none" : "source-map",
    entry: {
        app: "./client.js",
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve( "./src" ),
            "node_modules",
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, "dist" ),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    },
    plugins,
};
```

Comment: Can you share your webpack config ?

Comment: @AjayVarghese i just did, but i have added all the loaders previously but i hope it works with your solutuon

Comment: Loader for CSS is missing in webpack config.

Comment: @AjayVarghese i had added it but after it failed to work i removed it, if you check the isomorphic link it has the weboackconfig

Comment: Can you try adding this https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader ?

Comment: I did @Ajay but to no effect says the same the program crashes at start

Comment: With the help of babel-plugin-css-modules-transform and mini-css-extract-plugin, I'm able to use CSS. I'll share the config in sometime

Comment: @AjayVarghese did you try with that package.. great thanks please do share will solve a lot of problem

Comment: I have posted the my config. Please try that and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Please select my answer as the Answer to the question, if it worked.

Comment: @Ajay i have yet to try i will in some time and let you know i am out and donot have access to my system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below configuration made CSS work 
Packages installed: 
babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node, babel-plugin-css-modules-transform, mini-css-extract-plugin, css-loader, style-loader 
index.js

```
require( "babel-register" )( {
presets: [ "env" ],
plugins: [
    [
        "css-modules-transform",
        {
            camelCase: true,
            extensions: [ ".css", ".scss" ],
        }
    ],
    "dynamic-import-node"
],
} );
require( "./src/server" );
```

webpack.config.js

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                },
                'css-loader'
            ],
        },
    ]
```

In webpack config, added following plugin

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "styles.css",
}),
```

In server.js, Added the following code inside head in htmlTemplate.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
```

Usage

```
import  "./../App.css";

<h2 className="wrapper">F1 2018 Season Calendar</h2>
```

Comment: Hey @AjayVarghese it works thanks great solution , saved my day. can you explain what happened here and how it worked .. as i just followed the step u mentioned but couldn't get any insights , it will be help full if you share some insights. also with this i am not able to use scss , i think i need `scss loader  ` for it and also the module concept is not working , like css modules for react. if you could add that it will become a complete solution for others using this library .. thank you

Comment: For SSR, rendering happens twice, one in server and in client. In server, normal CSS loader won't work. css-modules-transform will handle this part, That's what I've written in index.js. This one is a very basic CSS setup. For sass or CSS-modules, you can add the config in webpack.config.js. Hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've went crazy trying to setup it up myself following all the mentioned approaches with no luck. In my case I'm using css-loader for create css modules syntax and SSR for React modules that aren't really big.

As someone mentioned because webpack will run twice you'll end with different class names which will make pop up some errors on the console saying that your server and client markups are different. To mitigate that you can create your own loader.

The idea is to store the value of the output from css-loader from one of the webpack compilations and use that for the next one. It might not be for what a loader is designed for but it does the job.

```
 /**
 * @typedef {Object} LoaderOptions
 * @property {"client" | "server"} type
 */

const mapContent = new Map();

/**
 * @param {LoaderOptions} options
 * @returns boolean
 */
const optionsValidator = (options) => {
  return (
    typeof options === 'object' &&
    'type' in options &&
    typeof options.type === 'string' &&
    (options.type === 'client' || options.type === 'server')
  );
};

module.exports = function (source) {
  /**
    @type import('./node_modules/webpack/types').LoaderContext<LoaderOptions>
   */
  const loader = this;
  const options = loader.getOptions();
  const logger = loader.getLogger();

  if (!optionsValidator(options)) {
    logger.error('css-ssr-replacer-loader. Only valid props are "type" with values of "client" or "server"');
  }

  const isClient = options.type === 'client';

  if (isClient) {
    mapContent.set(loader.resourcePath, Buffer.from(source));
  }

  return isClient ? source : mapContent.get(loader.resourcePath);
};
```

And then on your webpack you need to add something like the following

```
const webpackConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'howEverYouWantToCallTheLoader',
            options: {
              type: 'client' || 'server'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
                localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]',
                mode: 'local'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
      howEverYouWantToCallTheLoader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'pathToYourLoader.js')
    }
  }
};
```